# R grep and exact matches

Tags: regex, r

It seems grep is "greedy" in the way it returns matches. Assuming I've the following data:

```
Sources <- c(
                "Coal burning plant",
                "General plant",
                "coalescent plantation",
                "Charcoal burning plant"
        )

Registry <- seq(from = 1100, to = 1103, by = 1)

df <- data.frame(Registry, Sources)
```

If I perform `grep("(?=.*[Pp]lant)(?=.*[Cc]oal)", df$Sources, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)`, it returns

```
"Coal burning plant"     
"coalescent plantation"  
"Charcoal burning plant"
```

However, I only want to return exact match, i.e. only where "coal" and "plant" occur. I don't want "coalescent", "plantation" and so on. So for this, I only want to see `"Coal burning plant"`

Comment: Just use `==` then if you want an exact match: `df$Sources[df$Sources == "Coal burning plant"]`

Comment: @thelatemail That will work in this instance. But imagine if I have other entries such as "Coal steam engine plant", "Diesel coal plant", etc. I want to return those as well.

Comment: It's really not the same question. If you change people.jpg in that question to say peoples and and then do a grep in which you look for people, it will return the occurrence with "peoples". You can run the following to see what I am saying: `x <- c(
        "imageUploaded,peoples,more,comma,separated,stuff",
        "imageUploaded",
        "people.jpg"
)

xmatches <- intersect(
        grep("imageUploaded",x,fixed=TRUE),
        grep("people",x,fixed=TRUE)
)
x[xmatches]`

Comment: It looks very similar to me. You want to return matches with "coal" and "plant", they wanted to return matches with "imageUploaded" and "people.jpg".

Comment: But assuming they have "people.jpgS" but only want to return "people.jpg", the function as written will not differentiate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use word boundaries `\b` around your word patterns. A word boundary does not consume any characters. It asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not. You may also want to consider using the inline `(?i)` modifier for case-insensitive matching.

```
grep('(?i)(?=.*\\bplant\\b)(?=.*\\bcoal\\b)', df$Sources, perl=T, value=T)
```

[**Working Demo**](http://ideone.com/15zOGB)

Comment: Just checked it. That's what happens when you have newbies on board.

Comment: I noticed that if I added say "kerosene burner" to Sources and then tried to modify the grep function to also look for "kerosene", the function breaks down. Does it mean one can't have more than two conditions in this function? `grep('(?i)(?=.*\\bplant\\b)|(?=.*\\bcoal\\b)|(?=.*\\kerosene\\b)', df$Sources, perl=T, value=T)`

Comment: I ran it with \\b but noticed it doesn't appear to consider the 3rd argument.

Comment: Certainly. I must have mistyped. It does appear one can have any number of conditions. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

If you always want the order "coal" then "plant", then this should work

```
grep("\\b[Cc]oal\\b.*\\b[Pp]lant\\b", Sources, perl = TRUE, value=T)
```

Here we add `\b` match which stands for a word boundary. You can add the word boundaries to your original attempt we well

```
grep("(?=.*\\b[Pp]lant\\b)(?=.*\\b[Cc]oal\\b)", Sources, 
    perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

Comment: The second option is solid as order doesn't matter. Thanks.